# careers.stackoverflow.com profile link bug

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs, profile-page

I just got a careers.stackoverflow.com profile and I linked to my website. I use ssl encryption so my website link was `https://mywebsite.com` so after that I saved my profile and clicked on the link and I got on this page: `https//mywebsite.com` so there was no ":". I looked in the page source and saw that they added another http:// so the link was `http://https://mywebsite.com`. It looks like they can't handle https:// in their links.

Comment: We detected an invalid domain linked in your post. This is likely caused due to sample code not being in a code block. (this message will be automatically removed when the link is fixed)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks for the report micha.  This is fixed now.

Comment: @Jason_Punyon this is not fixed